# AppstoreConnect payments reports are not updating

Tags: app-store, app-store-connect

I have more than $400 in AppstoreConnect in my proceeding for the month of December but in the Payments and reports section, it's not updating any amount of the month of December and not showing any units sold.

I have complete details available in Sales & Proceeding but under the Payments & reports section it's not showing anything for the whole month of December and it's not continuing in Jan 2022 as well.

The last payment I received was in October 2021, in November 2021 I didn't match the minimal amount goal and my amount carries forward but from that

It's not updating for December and I think in Jan it will continue as well.

I tried contacting Apple and it's more than 2 weeks and no reply from them as well.

Any help would be great.

You can see it's updated on 30th December 2021
[image: You can see it's updated on 30th December 2021]

You can see proceeds on month December 2021

[image: You can see proceeds on month December 2021]

Comment: For what it's worth, I am also seeing similarly incomplete data for December. I hope this is just a reporting issue that will be resolved in the next few days.

Comment: any news about it? i'm having the same problem in january sales

Comment: @LeMag it was Apple's problem, auto fixed and happened again many time. just ignore they will update it